# How to bind a List<string> in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I'm searching for a good way to bind a `List<string>` to a form in MVC3. Right now I have 2 options:

- Use a ListBox with a textbox, add/delete button in jquery and do a select all items before posting my form
- Use a `<li>` that will contains a `<input type="hidden" />` with the value also with a add/delete button in jquery

I'm sure there is easyer way to do this but I did not found anything here so I'm asking for help. My concern is to add different bussiness units (string) to a company while editing the company other properties (name, address..).

Thanks!

Comment: I found something here. maybe it helps : http://codes.codedigest.com/codedigest/90-how-to-add--remove-listitems-from-one-listbox-to-another-using-jquery-.aspx

Comment: Thanks but I know how to do it, I already do it in an other project, it's just that I don't find it "pretty" to something that I do often in a project, I taught I could find a better solution.

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look at the knockoutjs list binding examples and code. Whether you're binding to a select multiple, select !multiple, ol, ul, or even a stack of divs, it makes the client code "prettier" IMO.

Comment: like this link : http://knockoutjs.com/examples/betterList.html? How would you do this in MVC(.Net)? It looks a lot like what I do, but thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my code for the first option, if anyone find a better solution, let me know!

Html/Razor :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="AddBusinessUnit" class="control-label">@Strings.BusinessUnit</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append">
                        <input type="text" class="span2" size="16" id="AddBusinessUnit" />
                        <button class="btn" type="button" id="add-business-unit">@Strings.Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.BusinessUnits, SelectLists.BusinessUnits(Model.BusinessUnits, false), new { Multiple = "multiple" })<br/>
                    <a href="#" id="delete-business-unit">@Strings.DeleteSelectedElement</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="@Strings.Save" />
        <a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Company.Index())" class="btn">@Strings.Cancel</a>
    </div>
```

Js :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#add-business-unit').click(function (e) {
        var bu = $('#AddBusinessUnit').val();
        if (bu != '') {
            $('#BusinessUnits').append($('<option></option>').val(bu).html(bu));
            $('#AddBusinessUnit').val('');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#delete-business-unit').click(function (e) {
        $('#BusinessUnits :selected').remove();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
        $('#BusinessUnits option').attr('selected', 'selected');
    });

});
```

The SelectList :

```
public static class SelectLists
    {
        public static IList<SelectListItem> BusinessUnits(IList<string> bussinessUnits, bool addEmpty, string selected = "")
        {
            var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            if(addEmpty) list.Add(new SelectListItem());
            list.AddRange(bussinessUnits.Select(businessUnit => new SelectListItem {Selected = selected == businessUnit, Text = businessUnit, Value = businessUnit}));

            return list;
        }
    }
```

It will bind to my property `public virtual IList<string> BusinessUnits { get; set; }` in my model.

Hope it can helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using a ListBox seems like a good way to achieve that. Then you could have a textbox and an add button next to it that will append a new element to the listbox and a delete button that will remove the selected items from the ListBox all using client side jquery. And when the form is submitted, since you have used a ListBox (`<select>` with `multiple="multiple"`) it will automatically bind to a property on your view model of type `List<string>` and you will be able to fetch the selected values.